# Grab или Scrapy. Web Crawling

Tags: python, grab

Приветствую. Подскажите пожалуйста что выбрать для изучения, Grab или Scrappy? В чем их отличие? Сам новичек, выбираю. У кого имеется уже хороший опыт? Работаю в Linux Ubuntu, если это имеет значение. Заранее благодарен!

Comment: А почему именно эти библиотеки? Есть еще и lxml, beautifulsoup4, html5lib и ряд др.

Comment: Ну по ряду причин хотел узнать именно об этих 2х. Конечно их много) Но интересуют эти) Чтобы не разводить холивар)

Comment: для изучение лучше тот, по которому нашли уроки

Comment: Тоже верно. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз вы задаете вопрос тут, в русском комьюнити, то лучше взгляните на Grub - статьи о Scrapy обычно на английском.

Comment: А на английском комьюнити профиль у меня этот же?

Comment: Должен быть такой же. Но там такие вопросы задавать не советую - не оценят.

Comment: А что там оценят только вопросы уже от профи?